# Trendline is not working in Amcharts Gantt chart

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart, trendline

I am trying to show a Trend line in amchart's Gantt Chart. my Code

```
    "trendLines": [{


    "finalValue": 'John',
    "initialValue": "Kendra",

    "initialDate": '2015-01-01',
    "finalDate": '2015-07-01',
    "lineColor": "#CC0000"
}],
```

The chart has date in X axis and categories in Y axis. [Gantt Chart screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBqTO.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `initialValue` and `finalValue` for the value axis, even if the value axis is date-based. You'll have to convert the string-based date to a millisecond timestamp, which can be done using [`AmCharts.stringToDate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#stringToDate). The Y axis in the Gantt chart is a category axis, so you need to use `initialCategory` and `finalCategory`.

```
"trendLines": [{
  "initialCategory": "John",
  "finalCategory": "Kendra",
  "initialValue": AmCharts.stringToDate("2015-01-01 07:00", "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN"),
  "finalValue": AmCharts.stringToDate("2015-01-01 10:00", "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN"),
}],
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5043d69eba56d618d2e3b6c37179cb87?editors=0010)